# "the most" and "for much"

Tags: time, adverbial-phrases

*For much of the 1990s, the Czech political landscape was dominated by the Civic Democratic Party.*

*The most of the 1990s the Czech political landscape was dominated by the Civic Democratic Party.*

I would like to ask whether two above sentences are grammatically correct (in terms of the time determination) and express the same thing.

Comment: The second is not correct.  It should be "For most" and would read identical to the first with that change.  "The most" is a comparison to a maximum quantity.  "For most" means that a majority of the time period mentioned applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example

> **For much** of the 1990s

means you are trying to emphasize a *duration* of time.

You could also express it as

> **For most** of the 1990s...
>   **During most** of the 1990s...

As @michaeldorgan points out ***the most*** is a type of comparison, and you might use

> In the 1990s, the Czech political landscape was dominated **the most** by the Civic Democratic Party.

which has more emphasis on *domination* rather than *duration*, but could be understood to have the same meaning as your original sentence.

Comment: A side question: you wrote "For much of the *1990's*", while OP wrote  "For much of the *1990s*". Are these two versions the same? If not, is there any difference?

Comment: @dan You are correct [here](https://www.ragan.com/Main/Articles/10_rules_for_using_the_apostrophe_45715.aspx), thanks!

Comment: In fact, I'd asked this question in this site. It seems that different people hold different opinions for this! It's really interesting. You can review this if you are interested in: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/147318/the-1990s-vs-the-1990s

Comment: Thankfully, they are both usually understood to be the same without ambiguity :)

Comment: According to this:https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55970/plurals-of-acronyms-letters-numbers-use-an-apostrophe-or-not, it seems that 1990s is more acceptable to most of people now.

Comment: Looks like 1990s is more safer than 1990's. I think 1990s is accepted by all, while 1990's is against (some strongly) by some people.